# Substitute lines after specific strings from another files content

Tags: awk, sed

I have three text files.

File 1

```
300,-4.45479329731605E-08,30.0000000534252
305,-3.24248685321522E-08,30.0000000626148
7505,-6.10348043414643E-08,29.9999998187525
7510,-2.97107304427854E-08,29.9999999033104
```

File 2

```
305
7510
```

When the lines in File 1 start with the numbers present in File 2, I want to substitute the lines in File 1 by the following lines in File 3

```
@1,2.0000,4.0
@2,10.0000,10.0
```

The desired output is:

```
300,-4.45479329731605E-08,30.0000000534252
@1,2.0000,4.0
7505,-6.10348043414643E-08,29.9999998187525
@2,10.0000,10.0
```

**Edit**: The files are with Windows line endings.

Comment: Use the `{}` in the editor to markup the data properly. Also, did you try anything?

Comment: and 3 lines of sample data should be enough, 1 unmatched in each source file and 1 matched record across all files should be enough. Did you look at `man join`? Good luck.

Comment: you could associate file2 and file3 witth: `paste file2 file3 >file4` then consider fiile1 to edit with insrtuction in file4.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ sub(/\r$/,"") }
FILENAME == ARGV[1] { idx[FNR] = $1; next }
FILENAME == ARGV[2] { map[idx[FNR]] = $0; next }
$1 in map { $0 = map[$1] }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file3 file1
300,-4.45479329731605E-08,30.0000000534252
@1,2.0000,4.0
7505,-6.10348043414643E-08,29.9999998187525
@2,10.0000,10.0
```

The above will work in any awk on any OS. If you want to keep `\r`s in the output then move the `sub()` call into the `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` block so it only affects `file2`.

Comment: what should I write in filename? can you please explain your script?

Comment: What do you mean `what should I write in filename?`. I used the same file names as you did, file1, file2, and file3.

Comment: I get the message: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Then you did something other than what I show in my answer and  there's a syntax error in whatever command you ran. Just do exactly what is in my answer.

Comment: I got it, works perfectly! As I am a beginner, can you please explain me the different steps of your script?

Comment: It's been a month since I answered this, I don't want to have to re-read the question to understand it again, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly.** 
It is convenient to merge your File 2 and File 3 line by line. You can achieve that with `paste` command:

```
paste -d"," file2 file3 > file23
```

As per your example, contents of file2:

```
305
7510
```

Contents of file3:

```
@1,2.0000,4.0
@2,10.0000,10.0
```

Resulting contents of file23:

```
305,@1,2.0000,4.0
7510,@2,10.0000,10.0
```

**Secondly.**
You can then use a simple AWK script to do what you need:

```
awk -v FS="," 'NR==FNR { d[$1]=substr($0,length($1)+2); next } d[$1] { $0=d[$1] } 1' file23 file1
```

Contents of file1:

```
300,-4.45479329731605E-08,30.0000000534252
305,-3.24248685321522E-08,30.0000000626148
7505,-6.10348043414643E-08,29.9999998187525
7510,-2.97107304427854E-08,29.9999999033104
```

Output:

```
300,-4.45479329731605E-08,30.0000000534252
@1,2.0000,4.0
7505,-6.10348043414643E-08,29.9999998187525
@2,10.0000,10.0
```

**P.S.** Generally questions like yours are considered off topic, since you didn't show any attempt to solve it by yourself. You should include code in questions like this.

Comment: thank you. In file 23, I get 305 in the first line, then ,@1,2.0000,4.0 in the second line, then 7510 in the third line and ,@2,10.0000,10.0 in the fourth line

Comment: @supernono06, then you can used AWK to merge your files: `awk '{ getline l < "file3"; print $0 "," l }' file2 > file23`

Comment: the problem with paste is still there, i.e. 305 and @1,2.0000,4.0 are not on the same line in file 23

Comment: if one removes the carriage returns in files 1, 2 and 3 by this command tr -d '\r' <file1.txt> file1n.txt, then it works very well

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{getline < "file3"}1' file2 file1
300,-4.45479329731605E-08,30.0000000534252
@1,2.0000,4.0
7505,-6.10348043414643E-08,29.9999998187525
@2,10.0000,10.0
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F, '               # comma delimiter
NR==FNR {                 # process file2
    a[$1]                 # hash to a 
    next                  # process next record in file2
}
$1 in a {                 # process file1. if first field value is in a
    getline < "file3"     # read a record from file3 and *)
}1' file2 file1           # output. mind the file order
```

`*)` If there are no records left in `file3` an empty record will output.

**Edit**: A Windows fixed variant for GNU awk (and mawk, untested in Windows):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";RS="\r\n"} NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{getline < "file3"}1' file2 file1
```

Comment: I get:

   
    line 1: 300,-4.45479329731605E-08,30.0000000534252  
    line 2:305,-3.24248685321522E-08,30.0000000626148  
    line 3:7505,-6.10348043414643E-08,29.9999998187525  
    line 4:@1,2.0000,4.0

Comment: Guessing you have files with DOS line endings. Add `BEGIN{RS="\r?\n"}` before the `NR==FNR...` part, after the first `'`. Which awk are you using?

Comment: I am using bash on Windows power shell

Comment: awk -F, 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n"} NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{getline < "file3"}1' file2 file1 works perfectly!

Comment: `? `in `RS="\r?\n"` makes the `\r` in Windows `\r\n` line ending conditional so that form should work in Windows and Unices. How about Macs? Anyone?

Comment: @JamesBrown multi-char RS is gawk-only, all other awks given `RS='\r?\n'` will just set RS to `\r` and ignore the rest of the string. @supernono06 make sure to read and fully understand http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline before considering using getline as it always looks simple but almost never actually is. The getline code in the above, for example, will fail silently and cryptically in some situations.